# How do I remove the "Home" link from the Woocommerce breadcrumb?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Right now on my woocommerce shop the breadcrumb reads "Home > Shop > Product Category > Product > etc".

I Would like to remove the home link so the breadcrumb trail starts with "Shop" as the first link.

Thanks!

Comment: What theme are you using? It is that the display of breadcumbs vary from theme to theme.

Answer (score 6):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults', function( $defaults ) {
    unset($defaults['home']); //removes home link.
    return $defaults; //returns rest of links
});
```

the above code goes to your functions.php.

Comment: Do not forget the high priority parameter to ensure last execution.

add_filter('woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults', function( $defaults ) {
    unset($defaults['home']); //removes home link.
    return $defaults; //returns rest of links
}, 9999);

Comment: Hey is there by any chance a latest update to this because this is not working for me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also directly pass an empty string to the `woocommerce_breadcrumb` function.

```php
<?php woocommerce_breadcrumb( array( 'home' => '' ) ); ?>
```

The function take an `home` argument and if this argument is empty, the **home** link isn't added, see: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L2237

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove_home_from_breadcrumbs($defaults) {
    $defaults['home'] = '';
    return $defaults;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults', 'remove_home_from_breadcrumbs');
```